# find not returning expected files

Tags: find

I'm trying to find some large files in a specific location:

This command works and returns some results:

```
admin@tyrell:~$ sudo find /nfshome/*/.local/ -type f -size +1G -exec ls -lh {} \;
-rw-r--r-- 1 9917183 students 5.2G Jun  5  2017 /nfshome/9917183/.local/share/Trash/files/result_25.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 9918178 students 4.0G Sep  6  2018 /nfshome/9918178/.local/share/unity3d/Asset Store-5.x/Unity Technologies/Unity EssentialsSample Projects/3D Game Kit.unitypackage
-rw-r--r-- 1 9919185 students 2.1G Mar  6  2018 /nfshome/9919185/.local/share/Trash/files/agggg.avi
-rw-r--r-- 1 9919382 students 1.7G Jan 17  2017 /nfshome/9919382/.local/share/Trash/files/MageWar.avi
-rw-r--r-- 1 9921459 students 1.8G Apr 12 11:58 /nfshome/9921459/.local/share/Trash/files/takeout-20190412T182950Z-001(1).zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 9921459 students 1.8G Apr 12 11:58 /nfshome/9921459/.local/share/Trash/files/takeout-20190412T182950Z-001.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 9921459 students 1.4G Apr 12 11:56 /nfshome/9921459/.local/share/Trash/files/takeout-20190412T182950Z-003.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 9921459 students 1.4G Apr 12 11:58 /nfshome/9921459/.local/share/Trash/files/takeout-20190412T182950Z-003(1).zip
```

but if I try to narrow the search by adding one more subdirectory, `share/`, I get nothing, where I would expect to get the exact same result, because everything above is in `share/`:

```
admin@tyrell:~$ sudo find /nfshome/*/.local/share/ -type f -size +1G -exec ls -lh {} \;
admin@tyrell:~$
```

Why doesn't find return the same result as the first command?

Comment: Does your non-root user have access to the `share` subdirectories? If not, the shell would not be able to expand the search path glob pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this fails is to do with permissions and the wildcard `*` character. We can reproduce this on a local file-system like this:

1. Set up the scenario, a directory tree under `/tmp/top`:

   ```
   sudo -s <<'x'
   mkdir -p /tmp/top/{a,b}/dir/sub/
   touch /tmp/top/{a,b}/dir/sub/file
   chown root /tmp/top/?/dir
   chmod go= /tmp/top/?/dir
   x
   ```
2. Notice that we have no permission as an ordinary user to go below `/tmp/top/*/dir`:

   ```
   find /tmp/top/?/dir -type f
   find: ‘/tmp/top/a/dir’: Permission denied
   find: ‘/tmp/top/b/dir’: Permission denied
   ```
3. Try descending with root privileges from a directory that we *cannot reach* as an ordinary user:

   ```
   sudo find /tmp/top/*/dir/sub -type f
   find: ‘/tmp/top/*/dir/sub’: No such file or directory
   ```

   Remember the evaluation of shell wildcards happens before the command is executed. So what is happening here is that the path containing the wildcard `*` is expanded. Your ordinary user account cannot verify the existence of `sub`, and so the entire path cannot be verified. The wildcard remains as an asterisk (the default behaviour when a match fails) and the root privileged `find` is given the literal path `/tmp/top/*/dir/sub` to descend. This path does not exist, hence the error.
4. Try descending with root privileges from a directory that we can reach as an ordinary user:

   ```
   sudo find /tmp/top/*/dir -type f
   /tmp/top/a/dir/sub/file
   /tmp/top/b/dir/sub/file
   ```

   What happens here is similar, but with more useful consequences. The path `/tmp/top/*/dir` can be evaluated completely as your ordinary user, resulting in two paths `/tmp/top/a/dir` and `/tmp/top/b/dir`. These are passed to the root privileged `find`, and it can subsequently descend these - through the root-only subdirectory - and list the files it discovers.

In your situation, it is highly likely that the `.local` directories in your wildcarded path cannot be accessed without root privileges, but the higher level directories are quite accessible. While you specify a path that can be evaluated as your ordinary user account, the `find` can proceed with the expanded set of paths. As soon as you specify a path that cannot be evaluated in the context of your ordinary user account, the expansion fails and `find` is passed a path that contains a literal `*` character. This of course fails to match and the `find` fails.

To resolve the issue you simply need to defer the evaluation of the path until your command is running as root:

```
sudo bash -c "find /nfshome/*/.local/ -type f -size +1G -exec ls -lh {} \;"
```

Answer (score 4):

In your command, the `sudo` only gives extra privileges to the `find` command, not to the shell.  So if you start up high, `find` is able to descend into the filetree and show you the contents.

But your shell is trying to expand the `*`.  If your user does not have privileges to inspect the contents of `/nfshome/*/.local`, then it will not be able to match to any files within (such as `/nfshome/*/.local/share`).  Without a match, nothing is passed to `find`.

You can see this by examining the output of `echo /nfshome/*/.local` and `echo /nfshome/*/.local/share`.  The second will probably be empty.

It's not clear *why* you want to do the second command when the first one appears to work.  You could run the entire command in a subshell, and execute it with `sudo`.  Such as `sudo -c  "find ..."`

Comment: Is there a way around this?

Comment: BowlOfRed, it may be that the OP is finding too many files matching the size criterion, and by specifying the `/share` subdirectory they hope to reduce the number of matches to those that are more relevant to their task at hand.